Tooljet on Docker - Public Schema Error after upgrade
I am struggling a bit with my tooljet installation, here is the setup :

Debian 12 on dedicated hardware
installed with docker (docker-compose) as in the documentation

Everything was working fine, but i wanted to upgrade to latest image version.
Ended up doing bad things so i have to restart from scratch.
Removed the containers, kept the SQL backup,Apps backup,compose file and .env file.
docker-compose up -d do work and raise the app fine, asking for initial setup.
I use the official script to restore my old DB => Works fine, can connect with old users etc...
Things get ugly when i want to check my tables in the tooljet app
"The schema must be one of the following: public"
Yet, all the tables are here, but i cant see inside it.
Here is the error i can sometime find in the tooljet container logs
"hostname": "20b759d0510f",
"level": 50,
"msg":
    {
    "exception":
        {
        "code": "PGRST106",
        "context":
            {
            "internalTables":
                [
                    {
                    "id": "35924680-599c-4dbe-8c1f-320abdd45e14",
                    "tableName": "ACCOUNTS"
                    }
                ],
            "origin": "proxy_postgrest"
            },
        "details": null,
        "driverError":
            {
            "code": "PGRST106",
            "details": null,
            "hint": null,
            "message": "The schema must be one of the following: public"
            },
        "hint": null,
        "parameters":
            [
            ],
        "query": "The schema must be one of the following: public",
        "queryError":
            {
            "code": "PGRST106",
            "details": null,
            "driverError":
                {
                "code": "PGRST106",
                "details": null,
                "hint": null,
                "message": "The schema must be one of the following: public"
                },
            "hint": null,
            "parameters":
                [
                ],
            "query":
                {
                "code": "PGRST106",
                "details": null,
                "hint": null,
                "message": "The schema must be one of the following: public"
                }
            }
        }

From my research, it seems that the problem is coming from postgrest ?
Might be wrong and dont know what to do more ! :)
Thank you !

Answer found on Tooljet community support:
Docker Compose file has been updated since the 3.0 version (Seems to be a Postgresql version change mostly)
Correct version of the docker compose file correct the issue.
